# How to return an empty field from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a stored procedure that has to return some dates. On some records there is a field that doesn't have data (a datetime field), and when the stored procedure is executed this fields returns values with a format like:

```
01/01/1900 12:00:00 a. m.
```

What i want to do is to return an empty field. I've tried with:

```
ISNULL(InvoiceDate, '') as DateOfRecord
```

But it is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by *not working*?

Comment: What is your definition of an "empty field"?  NULL?  An empty string?

Comment: I mean: still returning the same format '01/01/1900 12:00:00 a. m.'

Comment: The text of the proc and the underlying table schemas would help a lot here.

Comment: @STLDeveloper NULL or empty string is more useful than a confusing datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `CASE` if you want to return null when date is null.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN InvoiceDate  IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE InvoiceDate END as DateOfRecord
```

Comment: This won't work when the the date is equal to '1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM' because it will still return that datetime.

Comment: I cant believe this answer has any relation with question :D but it is accepted wow :)

Comment: @STLDeveloper Yeah, but his question field having no value. He wants to return empty value when source value is empty.

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin OP is not saying he wants to return `01/01/1900 12:00:00 a. m` value as NULL. OP stated `NULL` value is returned as `01/01/1900 12:00:00 a. m` when he is using `ISNULL`

Comment: @AB_87 - I disagree.  The question says "this fields returns values with a format like: "01/01/1900 12:00:00 a. m...".  Obviously the field value isn't `NULL`.

Comment: @STLDeveloper and what is `this field`? it is the field which does not have data (mentioned in the same statement).

Comment: @AB_87 - there is no way that `NULL` is returning as `01/01/1900 12:00:00 AM`.  The OP may have some confusion about the meaning of "a field that does not have data".  Is it `NULL`?  Is it the minimum `DATETIME` value (0)?  Again, there is NO WAY that the `NULL` field could be returning `01/01/1900 12:00:00 AM`.

Comment: @STLDeveloper `01/01/1900 12:00:00 AM` value must be in OPs application consuming this data. SSMS will not give AM PM format even for '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' in datetime column without using convert (OP only used ISNULL). My understanding of the question was NULL value is displayed as minimum datetime.

Comment: @STLDeveloper If your point is not about AM PM format and about `NULL` returned as `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`. It is because of ISNULL which OP is using.

Comment: @AB_87 - I understand the question differently than you.  I guess we must agree to disagree.

Comment: Yeah. Lets close this discussion :)

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable and set it to a null value and return it like:

```
DECLARE @mydate datetime
SET @mydate=null
SELECT @mydate --returns NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

use  `substring` function and cut the 1st 11 character if it is continuous return 01/01/1900 use then case when

```
case when substring(InvoiceDate,0,11)='01/01/1900' then null else InvoiceDate end 


substring('01/01/1900 12:00:00 a. m.',0,11) it will return 01/01/1900
```

Answer (score 0):

Internally, SQL Server stores DateTime data as a number.  When that number is zero, it is interpreted as `01/01/1900 12:00:00 AM`.

In your case, I believe that the value you have stored in that DateTime field is zero, so when you query it you get the results you see.

The simplest way to deal with this is probably to use a `CASE` expression in your query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, InvoiceDate) = '1900-01-01' THEN NULL
            ELSE InvoiceDate
       END  as DateOfRecord
```